# python : var's namespace code eval compiled ast code

Tags: python, namespaces, eval, abstract-syntax-tree, python-unittest

Using python3.4 and test the ast parse . Here is the test code .

```
import ast
import unittest


class TestAST(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ast(self):
        #compileobj = compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec")
        #compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec")
        eval(compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec"))
        self.assertTrue(x == 42)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

python test.py I got error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qocean\test\test_ast.py", line 13, in test_ast
    self.assertTrue(x == 42)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

While eval it in ipython : the x can be see like this :

```
In [3]:  eval(compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec"))

In [4]: x
Out[4]: 42
```

So the quetion is , while I can't use the var "x" , since the eval code is same in source code and ipython eval environemt . What's the difference ?

`#############################################`

**Update**: seem it is something relate to unittest module ,change test code in main() , it will success .

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    eval(compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec"))
    print (x)
```

after run . it show 42 .

more detailed , call this in func also failed

```
def test_eval():
    eval(compile(ast.parse("y=42"), '<input>', mode="exec"))
    print ("y is ", y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #unittest.main()
    test_eval()
```

Comment: The traceback links to an error in file `test_ast.py`, which has nothing to do with the line with `eval`

Comment: eval already done . so here the problem is why x can't find . if it x=42 already evaled .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, you can't create new local names dynamically. Those are baked in at the time the function is compiled to bytecode. Instead, you need to pass a dictionary to `exec` to be used as locals within that statement.

```
def test_ast(self):
    localvars = {}
    eval(compile(ast.parse("x=42"), '<input>', mode="exec"), localvars)
    self.assertTrue(localvars["x"] == 42)
```